# Appengine: can't delete deployed version

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed a couple of app versions which I can't delete now.

I tried to delete it using "[AppEngine](https://appengine.google.com/) 〉Administration 〉Versions"

[image: AppEngine Versions]
When I press "delete" to delete version 99:

[image: Deletion request window]

An attempt to delete a version always causes 500 error:

[image]

I've tried to overwrite them with new ones, but it didn't helped. I've tried to delete them a week ago and yesterday but it always fails. I'm afraid that after some time all versions will became undeletable (now I have 2 undeletable versions and deployed versions limit is ≈11).

How am I supposed to delete that versions? Are there alternative ways to delete deployed versions (appcfg wouldn't help)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be filed as a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4876&q=delete%20version&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) .... star it if that is not your own report to give it more weight